# If the sum of consecutive positive integers is 2018,what is the largest of those integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a unique answer? The options given are 1008,1009,1010 and 1011.
The question is from the 2018 SASMO exam.

Comment: $1007+1008=2015,1008+1009=2017,1009+1010=2019,1010+1011=2021.$ So none of the options is correct.

Comment: None of those.  All I find is $503+504+505+506$, and I cannot see any more solutions because $2018$ has only one odd factor greater than $1$.  Sum should have been $2019=1009+1010$ maybe?

Comment: $503 + 504 + 505 + 506$ is the only possible more than one, all positive, consecutive terms.  If there are odd $2k+1$ terms and the middle term is $n$ then add to $(2k+1)n$.  If there are even $2k$ terms and the middle two terms are $n,n+1$ they add to $k(2n+1)$.  So $2018=2*1009$ this only works if $k=2; n=504$.   See my answer.

Comment: 2018, like any positive integer, can be written as the sum of one consecutive positive integer.

Comment: Since the given options are roughly half the consecutive numbers must around half so there must be two of them.  But as none $1007+1008, 1008+1009, 1009+1010,$ and $1010 + 1011$ it can't be any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of terms be $n,$ and the smallest of the lot $=a$

$\implies\dfrac n2\{2a+n-1\}=2018$

$\iff n^2+n(2a-1)-4036=0$

The discriminant $(2a-1)^2+4(4036)$ must be perfect square $=b^2$

$\implies b^2-(2a-1)^2=4(4036)$

As $b$ is odd $=2c-1$(say) where $c\ge1$

$4(4036)=(2c-1)^2-(2a-1)^2=4(c-a)(c+a-1)$

$\iff4036=(c-a)(c+a-1)$

As $c-a+c+a-1=2c-1$ which is odd, $c-a,c+a+1$ must be of opposite parity

$c-a$ is odd, it must be one of $\{\pm1,\pm1009\}$

$c+a-1$ is odd, it must be $=1009$

Answer (score 1):

If there are two consecutive integers then they are $n$ and $n+1$ and they add to $2n + 1 = 2018$ and $n = \frac {2017}2$ which is not an integer.

If there are $3$ consecutive integers then are $n-1, n, n+1$ and the add to $(n-1) + n + (n+1) = 3n = 2018$ and $n = \frac {2018}3$ which is not an integer.

If there are $2k+1$, an odd number of consecutive integers they are $n-k, n-(k-1),.....,n,....,n+k-1, n+k$ and then add to $(2k+1)n = 2018$ so $n = \frac {2018}{2k+1}$.  $2018 = 2*1009$ and $1009$ is the prime.  So the only way this could be is if $2k+1 = 1009$ or $k = 504$ and $n= 2$.  BUt that means the consecutive integers are $-502.... 506$.  But those aren't all positive.

If there are $2k$, an even number of consecutive integers the are $n-k+1,....,n,n+1, ...,n+k$ and they add to $k(2n+1)= 2018$.  So $n = \frac{\frac {2018}k-1}2$.  The only reasonable value for $k$ is $2$, ($k$ odd won't give an integer and $k=2018$ will yield $n=0$ and $2$ and $2018$ are the only even number that divide $2018$) and $n = 504$ and $2k=4$ so $2018 = 503+504 + 505 + 506 = 2018$.

So the answer is $506$.

That is the only way to have $2018$ be the sum of more than one consecutive positive integers.

Comment: Good solution, the second case, which leads to $k(2n+1)=2018$, can I think be handled  slightly easier by the same argument as in the first case: The only odd positive divisors of $2018$ are $1$ and $1009$, which leads to $n=0$ (not a solution) and the real one.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of consecutive integers from $a$ to $b$ is $\frac{(b-a+1)(b+a)}2$. Note that the parity of $b-a+1$ and $b+a$ are different, so we need to find a factorization of $2\cdot2018=4036$ into an odd integer times an even integer; e.g.
$$
4036=4\cdot1009=4036\cdot1
$$
Since $1009$ is prime, these are the only such factorizations. The second factorization leads to the trivial sum of one integer $a=b=2018$. The first leads to $a=503$ and $b=506$.